# Allowing 3rd party tenant users to login to our application

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2b

We've got an application which uses a separate authentication server to handle logins. The authentication server uses ASP.NET Identity to manage credentials. This setup is OK for small businesses but larger organisations would like to use their Azure AD to manage access to our application. So we set out to provide this capability but I'm kinda stuck setting it up.

We created a SCIM service so users could be synced with our app and this is working fine. So step 1 is done, getting the users in our app. Now the login part. Next I setup Azure AD and added an OpenID Connect Authentication to the login page of our authentication server. This is all working great with our own Azure AD users, but how can I allow the users of the 3rd party organisations to also login? When the Azure B2C login box appears the user should be redirected to the organisations Azure AD login page so they can login using their work credentials. How can I setup this redirect in Azure AD for the application we added?

The organisation we like to connect with also has Azure AD and has setup an enterprise app for our app to activate the provisioning via SCIM. They want to activate Single Sign-On (SSO) but I'm a bit lost on how to provide them with the Basic SAML configuration that they need to fill in.

Answer (score 1):

B2C SSO and Azure AD Provisioning Service (SCIM) for Applications registered in B2C directory is not supported. Please refer the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/isv-automatic-provisioning-multi-tenant-apps#choose-a-provisioning-method) which tells that Support for non-enterprise accounts (B2C), SCIM is not supporting